# How to make volumes permanent with Docker Compose v2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, singlestore

*I realize other people have had similar questions but this uses v2 compose file format and I didn't find anything for that.*

I want to make a very simple test app to play around with MemSQL but I can't get volumes to not get deleted after `docker-compose down`. If I've understood Docker Docs right, volumes shouldn't be deleted without explicitly telling it to. Everything seems to work with `docker-compose up` but after going down and then up again all data gets deleted from the database.

As recommended as a good practice, I'm using separate memsqldata service as a separate data layer.

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    app:
        build: .
        links:
            - memsql
    memsql:
        image: memsql/quickstart
        volumes_from:
            - memsqldata
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
            - "9000:9000"
    memsqldata:
        image: memsql/quickstart
        command: /bin/true
        volumes:
            - memsqldatavolume:/data

volumes:
    memsqldatavolume:
        driver: local
```

Comment: I would try without the memsqldata container. Since you're using a named volume, you don't need a data volume container.  I tried `down`, and it doesn't remove any volumes by default.

Comment: Is it possible that the mysql data isn't in the volume at all? I don't think it uses `/data` normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was traced back to a bad documentation from MemSQL. MemSQL data path in `memsql/quickstart` container is `/memsql` and not `/var/lib/memsql` like in a stand-alone installation (and in MemSQL docs), and definitely not `/data` like somebody told me.

Answer (score 32):

I realize this is an old and solved thread where the OP was pointing to a directory in the container rather than the volume they had mounted, but wanted to clear up some of the misinformation I'm seeing.

`docker-compose down` does not remove volumes, you need to run `docker-compose down -v` if you also want to delete volumes. Here's the help text straight from docker-compose (note the "by default" list):

```
$ docker-compose down --help
Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images
created by `up`.

By default, the only things removed are:

- Containers for services defined in the Compose file
- Networks defined in the `networks` section of the Compose file
- The default network, if one is used

Networks and volumes defined as `external` are never removed.

Usage: down [options]

Options:
...
    -v, --volumes       Remove named volumes declared in the `volumes` section
                        of the Compose file and anonymous volumes
                        attached to containers.
...

$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.12.0, build b31ff33
```

Here's a sample yml with a named volume to test and a dummy command:

```
$ cat docker-compose.vol-named.yml
version: '2'

volumes:
  data:

services:
  test:
    image: busybox
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    volumes:
    - data:/data

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.vol-named.yml up -d
Creating volume "test_data" with default driver
Creating test_test_1
```

After starting the container, the volume is initialized empty since the image is empty at that location. I created a quick hello world in that location:

```
$ docker exec -it test_test_1 /bin/sh
/ # ls -al /data
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May 23 01:24 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May 23 01:24 ..
/ # echo "hello volume" >/data/hello.txt
/ # ls -al /data
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May 23 01:24 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May 23 01:24 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            13 May 23 01:24 hello.txt
/ # cat /data/hello.txt
hello volume
/ # exit
```

The volume is visible outside of docker and is still there after a `docker-compose down`:

```
$ docker volume ls | grep test_
local               test_data

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.vol-named.yml down
Stopping test_test_1 ... done
Removing test_test_1 ... done
Removing network test_default

$ docker volume ls | grep test_
local               test_data
```

Recreating the container uses the old volume with the file still visible inside:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.vol-named.yml up -d
Creating network "test_default" with the default driver
Creating test_test_1

$ docker exec -it test_test_1 /bin/sh
/ # cat /data/hello.txt
hello volume
/ # exit
```

And running a `docker-compose down -v` finally removes both the container and the volume:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.vol-named.yml down -v
Stopping test_test_1 ... done
Removing test_test_1 ... done
Removing network test_default
Removing volume test_data

$ docker volume ls | grep test_

$
```

If you find your data is only being persisted if you use a stop/start rather than a down/up, then your data is being stored in the container (or possibly an anonymous volume) rather than your named volume, and the container is not persistent. Make sure the location for your data inside the container is correct to avoid this.

To debug where data is being stored in your container, I'd recommend using `docker diff` on a container. That will show all of the files created, modified, or deleted inside that container which will be lost when the container is deleted. E.g.:

```
$ docker run --name test-diff busybox \
  /bin/sh -c "echo hello docker >/etc/hello.conf"

$ docker diff test-diff
C /etc
A /etc/hello.conf
```

Comment: Nice clarification. +1

Comment: What would it mean for the data to be "in the container" rather than a volume? I assume anything stored in a directory that is mapped to a volume would be in a volume?

Comment: Yes, but as the OP showed, if you don't map the volume to the correct location, your data is not in a volume but rather the RW layer of the container. When you delete your container, all changes made to that container (mainly it's RW filesystem layer) that weren't stored in a volume are lost.

Comment: @BMitch "If you find your data is only being persisted if you use a stop/start rather than a down/up, then your data is being stored in the container rather than a volume, and the container is not persistent." I am not sure this is true. If you are relying on an anonymous volume (Like one defined in a Dockerfile), then when you create a new container from the image (by calling docker-compose up after docker-compose down) you will get a new volume.

Comment: @jminardi good point, I forget to include disclaimers about anonymous volumes because I strongly recommend against using them. That also goes for recommending against ever defining `VOLUME` inside the Dockerfile. I believe there's some logic in compose to reuse the previous anonymous volume, but that may not survive a `down` command.

Comment: I agree with the idea that `VOLUME` should not be used in a Dockerfile, but unfortunately many official Dockerfiles make use of it, including `memsql` and `mongo`.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `docker-compose down` and if you look at the docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/)

> Stop containers and remove containers, networks, volumes, and images
>   created by `up`. Only containers and networks are removed by default.

You are right, it should not remove volumes (by default). It may be a bug or you may have changed the default configuration. But I think the right command for you is `docker-compose stop`. I will try to make some tests with simplier cases for `down` command.

Comment: I'm using everything in default config. I'm no Docker expert so I'm hoping there's sensible defaults chosen ;) Installed Toolbox yesterday so everything should be at the latest versions: docker-compose version 1.6.0, build d99cad6, docker-py version: 1.7.0.

Comment: Did you already try to buid and run your `memsqldata` alone, provide some files in your volume, then stop it/remove the container and see if there are still the files ?

Comment: Yes. I've been testing that same memsql structure for few days. I just tested that it works also if I do docker-compose stop. It's `down` that seems to be acting not the way it's suppose to.

Comment: I will try tomorrow with a version 2 docker-compose and I will give some feedback. But for the moment, in first version, it's ok, still working here.

Comment: I tried as I said with a version 2 docker-compose file. I'm mounting my volume on a host's directory. After `docker-compose down`, the volume are not removed. Is your database really using the `/data` directory for saving your data ?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to use `docker-compose stop` instead of `docker-compose down`. And then `docker-compose start` to restart.

According to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/), `down` "stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by up."

Comment: `docker-compose down` does not delete volumes unless you pass the `-v` option.

Comment: That is not what I am seeing, with this [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/jstray/cjworkbench-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file. Down definitely deletes the volume even without `-v`. If there is something I am doing wrong I would love to know! I live in fear of accidentally losing my database.

Comment: That would probably be worth asking as a separate question with all the details instead of trying to debug in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this helps or not. When you use `docker-compose up -d` the container is downloaded and images created. To stop the docker images, use `docker-compose down`, and the images will remain and can be restarted with `docker-compose start`

I was using the up/down commands and kept losing my data until I tried the stop/start and now data persists.

Comment: After a couple of hours of searching this solved my problem!

Comment: This is wrong. `docker-compose down` deletes volumes. I think that's what Bobby meant to say though.

Comment: Stop/Start will keep the same containers, if you lose data from a down/up, then you are not storing your data in a volume, rather your data is in the container itself which should not be considered persistent. `docker-compose down` does not delete volumes unless you include the `-v` option too.